# In parallelogram $ABCD$ if $AC>BD$, then $\measuredangle B>\measuredangle A$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

If we have the parallelogram $ABCD$ $(AB\parallel CD)$, could someone explain to me how if the diagonal $AC$ is greater than the diagonal $BD$, then we can conclude that $\measuredangle ABC>\measuredangle BAD$?
I really have difficulties with proving such basic problems.

Comment: have you tried using the Cosine Rule?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider triangles formed by one side and diagonals. If you know that one side in a triangle is larger than another one, what can be said about opposite angles?

Comment: From $\triangle BOC$ we can conclude that $\measuredangle OBC>\measuredangle BOC$ but I don't see how this helps.

Comment: Either you made a typo, or what you said is not necessarily true. You should also consider $\triangle AOB$

Comment: @mat1: $AC > BD \Rightarrow OC > OB \Rightarrow \angle OBC > \angle OCB$, $OC > OD \Rightarrow \angle ODC > \angle OCD$. $\angle ABC = \angle OBC + \angle OBA = \angle OBC + \angle ODC > \angle OCB + \angle OCD = \angle BCD$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $AB=x=CD$ and $AD=y=BC$ and let $\angle ABC=\theta$ and $\angle BAD=\phi$.

Then by the Cosine Rule,
$$AC^2=x^2+y^2-2xy\cos \theta$$
and
$$BD^2=x^2+y^2-2xy\cos\phi$$

Then $$AC>BD\implies AC^2>BD^2\implies \cos\theta<\cos\phi\implies \theta>\phi$$